# How to add on Press guester handling to a Maker added using AGSGraphicsOverlay?

Tags: ios, arcgis

My first thought was to add a guester handler and listen for on press.. but I dont see any `UIView` in use when rendering simple marker using graphics overlay. What is the correct way to do it? Thanks

This is what I am using:

```
AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol *symbol = [[AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol alloc] initWithStyle:AGSSimpleMarkerSymbolStyleCircle color:UIColor.redColor size:20];

AGSPoint *point = [[AGSPoint alloc] initWithCLLocationCoordinate2D: *coords];

AGSGraphic *graphics = [[AGSGraphic alloc] initWithGeometry:point symbol:symbol attributes:nil];

[_agsGraphicsOverlay.graphics addObject:graphics];
```